# Is $y=0^x$ really a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, convention, indeterminate-forms

I know that there are three main options when it comes to dealing with $0^0$: $$0^0=0$$ $$0^0=1$$ $$\nexists x(x=0^0)$$My question is, do we have to assert that one of these conditions is true in order to declare $y=0^x$ a function? I ask because Desmos plots both $(0,0)$ AND $(0,1)$ (to show the controversy I suppose). Thanks for your time!

Comment: How do you treat $0^x$ when $x$ is negative?

Comment: @Henry It would be undefined, because $0^{-n},n\in\Bbb{N}$ would cause division by $0$.

Comment: @Koro The domain is $(0,\infty)$ for sure, but whether $0$ is included is undecided, right?

Comment: You can't declare functions without specifying domains.  And you can't declare a function that is not  defined on any points of the domain.  So if you domain is a subset of positive numbers you can declare the function is $y=0$ and be done.  If your domain includes any non-positive values you can *not* declare $y=0^x$ at all.

Comment: " The domain is (0,∞) for sure, but whether 0 is included is undecided, right? "  If the domain is $(0, \infty)$ then $0$ is most certainly *not* included.  There is utterly no ambiguity in that at all.  Becase $(0,  \infty)= \{x\in \mathbb R| x > 0\}$ and $0 \not > 0$ so so $0 \not \in (0,\infty)$.  No indecision.

Comment: @fleablood So are you answering my question in the positive? Because to define the domain is to define $0^0$. And by for sure, I meant that $(0,\infty)$ (notice the round brackets) is the certain part of it.

Comment: No!  The domain is $(0,\infty)$ and $0$ is !!!!!*NOT*!!!!! in the domain!  So you don't have to worry about what $0^0$ because $x$ will !!!!!*NEVER*!!!!!!! equal $0$.

Comment: If $x \in (0, \infty)$ then $x \ne 0$ and $x > 0$ and $0^x = 0$.  That's *ALL* there is to it.  There is *NOTHING* else to worry about.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't catch that, could you use more exclamation marks? :P I get what you're saying, but the question was whether we have to assert *either* $0^0=0$ or $0^0=1$ for $y=0^x$ to be a function with the domain $[0,\infty)$. Obviously it's a function if the domain doesn't include $0$.

Comment: doesn't this then come down to your definition of what a function is?

Comment: @Vaas There is a standard definition for a function.

Comment: @MicahWindsor well yes and no, there's multiple ways of looking at something with a fairly concrete definition, example would be the relational understanding of functions vs as an element of a Cartesian product. My point generally stands from the idea of whether you need to do X or need to do Y, it's fairly well understood that $0^0$ is undefined, the next question is then: is it a function if it **"has"** an undefined value? as for desmos? that's as simply explained as poor programming. all it would require is an exception in the code.

Comment: "but the question was whether we have to assert either 00=0 or 00=1 for y=0x to be a function with the domain [0,∞)"  If that was the question, then why didn't you *ASK* that.  But even so, I *did* answer that.  If the functions domain is $[0,\infty)$ then the function can *not* be $y=0^x$.  You can have a function where $y=0^x$ where $x > 0$ and $y = Babar\ the\ elephant$ where $x = 0$ if you want but that function is *not* $y = 0^x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a rule is such that $r(k)$ is not defined then you simply can *not* define a function as being $f(x) = r(x)$ is $k$ is in the domain. Period.

If the domain of the function is $[0, \infty)$ then the function can *not* be $f(x) = 0^x$.  It just plain can not be.

If you want to a function to be $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=0^x$ when $x\ne 0$ then you (must/only need to) *extend* the definition of the function to include a value for $f(0)$.  So for example:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}0^x & \text{if }x \ne 0\\\frac 1{\sqrt \pi}+27.3&\text{if }x = 0\end{cases}$.

What you set $f(0)$ to doesn't matter.  You can set it to $0$ if you want (that's the only value that will make the function continuous FWIW) or you can set it to $1$ or you can set it to $\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} + 27.3$.  Whatever you set it to the function will *not* be $f(x) = 0^x$.  That is simply *not* an option if $0\in $ the domain of the function.  Period.

$0^0$ will remain undefined.